# In ZFC, is it possible for a set to be an element of one of its elements?

Tags: set-theory

I'd like to know if $x\in y \land y\in x$ is possible under the ZFC set theory.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I feel that I close that one as a duplicate about once a month.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But I'm asking a different question.

Comment: No, you really don't. And if you read the answers, you'll find out why. But fine, I'll find you more duplicates.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks